# How to compare color object in react native while setting state

Tags: react-native, conditional-statements, state

Can some one please help me in comparing color object in react native.
Generally in swift I would have done so:

```
if aColorObj == UIColorClass.white{
  aColorObj = UIColorClass.gray
}
```

How to do similar in react native below:

```
onPressLearnMore() {

  this.setState = {
    /*
      how to write this:
       if mbackgroundColor == 'white'{
      mbackgroundColor = 'red'
      }else if mbackgroundColor == 'gray'{
      mbackgroundColor = 'white'
      } 
    */
  };
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution here is too, save the initial background color in a state, have colors object that you can use to compare color with.

```
const Colors = {
  Grey: '#DCDCDC',
  White: '#FFFFFF',
  Blue: '#0000FF',
  Black: '#000000',
};


state = {
  backgroundColor: Colors.White,
};

<View
    style={[
      styles.container,
      { backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor }, // set background color here from state
    ]}>
```

Then you can use a function to check background color.

```
checkBackgroundColor = () => {

  if (this.state.backgroundColor === Colors.Blue) {
    console.log("It's blue");

    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: Colors.White,
    });
  }
  ....
};
```

[snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/carefree-bacon)