# How to check if all elements have same background

Tags: reactjs

I\ve builded a game in React.js.Its a memory game where you have to remember divs with same background.You click on the div and if all three divs have same color you pass the level, but my code guess only one instead of three divs and passes the level.Here is the code:

```
              let all=document.querySelectorAll(".wall");
              let o1=[0,25,29];
              let red="crimson";

          for(let f=0; f < o1.length; f++)  {

           if(this.state.asd==="MEMORIZE 3 RED COLORS" 
            && all[o1[f]].style.background===red)  {    
          
            //how to correct upper loop and condition
            
             }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You says: "but my code guess only one instead"

Then, it's supposing giving a true result for the first compare.

On this  `all[o1[f]].style.background===red)`, you should try:  `all[o1[f]].style.background=='red')`,

Another option, is use the hex code colors. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771163/how-to-compare-color-object-in-react-native-while-setting-state) an example.

Comment: Corrected, i wrote i variable called red with color "crimson".It suppose to click on three divs and if they are true you can pass to the next level,if they are not you can't go to the next level.